# Looking at the next word

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know how I can find a word which has the next one with the first letter capitalised.

For example:

```
ID        Testo

141      Vivo in una piccola città
22       Gli Stati Uniti sono una grande nazione
153      Il Regno Unito ha votato per uscire dall'Europa
64       Hugh Laurie ha interpretato Dr. House 
12       Mi piace bere birra.
```

My expected output would be:

```
ID        Testo                                                 Estratte

141      Vivo in una piccola città                              []
22       Gli Stati Uniti sono una grande nazione                [Gli Stati, Stati Uniti]
153      Il Regno Unito ha votato per uscire dall'Europa        [Il Regno, Regno Unito]
64       Hugh Laurie ha interpretato Dr. House                  [Hugh Laurie, Dr House]
12       Mi piace bere birra.                                   []
```

To extract letter capitalised I do:

```
df['Estratte'] = df['Testo'].str.findall(r'\b([A-Z][a-z]*)\b')
```

However this column collect only single words since the code does not look at the next word.
Could you please tell me which condition I should add to look at the next word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime regex is not always good , let us try `split` with `explode`

```
s=df.Testo.str.split(' ').explode()
s2=s.groupby(level=0).shift(-1)
assign=(s + ' ' + s2)[s.str.istitle() & s2.str.isttimeitle()].groupby(level=0).agg(list)
Out[244]: 
1    [Gli Stati, Stati Uniti]
2     [Il Regno, Regno Unito]
3    [Hugh Laurie, Dr. House]
Name: Testo, dtype: object
df['New']=assign
# notice after assign the not find row will be assign as NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use my code below

```
def getCapitalize(myStr):
    words = myStr.split()
    for i in range(0, len(words) - 1):
        if (words[i][0].isupper() and words[i+1][0].isupper()):
            yield f"{words[i]} {words[i+1]}"
```

This function will create a generator and you will have to convert to a list or wtv

Answer (score 0):

````
import re
import pandas as pd

x = {141 : 'Vivo in una piccola città',  22: 'Gli Stati Uniti sono una grande nazione', 
      153 : 'Il Regno Unito ha votato per uscire dall\'Europa',  64 : 'Hugh Laurie ha interpretato Dr. House',  12 :'Mi piace bere birra.'}

df = pd.DataFrame(x.items(), columns = ['id', 'testo'])

caps = []
vals = df.testo

for string in vals:
    string = string.split(' ')
    string = string[1:]
    string = ' '.join(string)
    caps.append(re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]+)', string))

df['Estratte'] = caps```
````

Answer (score 0):

Why not match a word starting with capital letter but not at the start of  line

```
df.Testo.str.findall('(?<!^)([A-Z]\w+)')
```

or

```
df.Testo.str.findall('(?<!^)[A-Z][a-z]+')


0                        []
1            [Stati, Uniti]
2    [Regno, Unito, Europa]
3       [Laurie, Dr, House]
4                        []
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest is to use regex, search (pattern-space-pattern), with overlapping:

```
import regex as re
df['Estratte'] = df.Testo.apply(lambda x: re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]+[ ][A-Z][a-z]+', x, overlapped=True))
```